# If-Else function to store the pallets into one of three pallet racks when set condition is true

Tags: anylogic

I would like to store my pallets into my pallet racks if the set conditions are true. The function works but for now it **stores all of my pallets into pallet rack PRD 6**. I think that is because of the initialization where int typeID = 0. The different typeIDs came from my database. Also when my typeID is 30 it stores into PRD6 instead of PRD8.

I tried to include the typeID (int) into my arguments but when I insert the function into the rackstore block it says that the function is not applicable.
What do you think? Thank you for very much.

[image: function]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong as `typeID` is always zero. Always. You set it yourself at the first line!

You must use an argument `typeID` in your function. Then call it with whatever dbase ID you need, i.e. loop through all entries in your dbase table and call the function for each entry's ID.

Feel free to share more details on your dbase setup and where you call your function :)

Comment: Okay thanks that was also my thought. I attached the database. The different typeIDs were insert at the certain time with the different amounts into my source block. Then they should get stored into the different racks. What do you mean with "loop through all entries in your dbase table and call the function for each entry's ID"? What exactly should I do now? :) Its very difficult and I am currently learning to use different functions in AnyLogic

Comment: could you help me please what I exactly should do now?

Comment: pleaase ask a specific new question, not "what should I do now". My time is very limited and I cannot provide free consulting here :-) Do a new question and show in detail what you tried, what you need, where the problem is... Put effort in and you will get answers. Ask lazily for "please tell me what to do" and things go quiet :-)